# Can we add properties to immutable object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, immutable.js, ecmascript-2017

An object is like:

```
const obj = [{name: 'Alex', age: 20}, {name: 'James', age: 22}];
```

This obect is immutable from Immutable.js.

Is it possible to add a new key for each object? example:

```
const obj = [{name: 'Alex', age: 20, city: 'New York'}, {name: 'James', age: 20, city: 'Rome'}];
```

Comment: What happens if you simply try adding properties to each object?

Comment: "*This obect is immutable from Immutable.js*" - the snippet you posted does not use immutable.js, it just creates normal array and object literals. Can you post some code that creates a real Immutable object?

Comment: Is your question answered? If so, mark the correct answer. If not, comment on the answers given and specify why those don't answer your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not if it’s immutable. But that is ok, you can copy all the properties over to a new structure and add whatever you need to that way:

```
const newData = obj.map(person => ({
  ...person,
  city: someLogicToDetermineCity(person)
}))

function someLogicToDetermineCity(person) {
  // logic based on person
  return city
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`const` doesn't create immutability - it just means that the **reference** assigned to it on creation cannot be changed later (which simply means that you cannot assign a new value to it).

See these examples:

```js
const a = {}

a = { name: "peter" } // => TypeError: invalid assignment to const `a'
```

However it's no problem to assign a property on `a`:

```js
const a = {}

a.name = "peter"

console.log(a); // => { "name": "peter" }
```

The same applies for `Array` objects:

```js
const arr = [{}]

arr.push(1);

arr[0].name="peter"

console.log(arr);
// [
//  {
//    "name": "peter"
//  },
//  1
// ]
```